# Hibernate 4 Multi-tenancy

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant

From the documents provided I learn that the hibernate4 allows multi-tenacity in three different levels.

Though what I cant understand is, whether we can have different set of entities for different tenants.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need multiple set of entities, the point of multi tenancy is to use the same relational structure (set of entities) but have multiple copies of it. One copy per tenant essentially.

I have written a short post on it you can find here[multi tenancy in hibernate 3](http://noobjuggler.blogspot.in/2012/03/multitenant-mode-for-dddcqrs-base.html)

Comment: Well.. I get the point. But the issue I face is that there are minor customization in entities - requested by tenants. Seems that achieving the functionality is a bit tough.